# String encoded incorrectly in powershell

Tags: powershell, text, character-encoding

I have a function to get my external IP from ifconfig.me. It returns what looks like a plain string from "http://ifconfig.me/ip"

```
function Get-ExternalIP
    {
    $url = "http://ifconfig.me/ip"
    $webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
    $ip = $webClient.downloadstring($url)
    return $ip
    }
```

This successfully returns what looks like an IP Address, however its not encoded in a way that it is properly handled by powershell.

```
$ip = Get-ExternalIP
$ip -as [ipaddress]
```

Fails.

All the functions I'm attempting to do with this string are failing. I'm importing a different IP as a string from a text file and comparing the two is failing even if they are 'identical'.

It gets worse, when I attempt to write it out to a text file I'm getting extra line breaks and a hex heditor shows loads of extra data thats not getting shown.

[image]
Top is the 'bad data', bottom is an example of how I would expect it to look.

I'm assuming that this is due to the encoding of the text object I'm extracting, but I'd like to understand how i can find out what the encoding is and re-encode it in a way that I can work with. I'm sure there is a simple cast(?) I can do? But I don't know how I would go about finding that out.

Comment: The "extra" data are [byte order marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: `$ip.trim() -as [ipaddress]` returns `TRUE` ! The value has an extra 'empty' cahr at the end.

Comment: @vonPryz the two characters at the beginning of the string are BOM, but if you look at the ret of the data there are extra

Comment: @Patrick The BOM as well as the additional null characters between the dots and digits come from saving the string to a file. Unless you specify the encoding explicitly, writing to a file in PowerShell defaults to Unicode (little endian UTF-16 encoding to be precise), which uses 2 bytes per character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by a trailing newline in the string returned by the website. The error becomes apparent when you cast the string to `[ipaddress]` instead of using the `-as` operator:

```
PS C:\> $ip = Get-ExternalIP
PS C:\> $ip
192.168.23.42

PS C:\> $ip -as [ipaddress]
PS C:\> [ipaddress]$ip
Cannot convert value "192.168.23.42
" to type "System.Net.IPAddress". Error: "An invalid IP address was specified."
At line:1 char:1
+ [ipaddress]$ip
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocation
```

Note that the closing double quote after the IP address is on the next line in the error message.

`Trim()` the string before returning it and the problem will disappear:

```psh
function Get-ExternalIP {
  $url = "http://ifconfig.me/ip"
  $webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
  $ip = $webClient.downloadstring($url)
  return $ip.Trim()
}
```

Comment: I could have sworn I'd tried with .trim() already but I've tested your version of that function and its worked properly this time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would use ASCII for your text output format

```
$ip = "255.255.255.255"
$ip | out-file -encoding ascii -Filepath C:\ascii_ip.txt
```

fyi, your test.txt image is likely in unicode format.   Compare that against this and you'll see.  The secret is in the BOM (byte order mark) "FF FE" which is like a file header for text files.

```
$ip | out-file -encoding unicode -Filepath C:\unicode_ip.txt
```

Comment: That you, I'd have liked to mark both answers as correct but @Ansgar's answer fixed the most annoying issue, but your answer has also been very helpful, thank you.